My self written http server code in c++ is refusing to connect
Below is my server.h file
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>

class Server {
    public:
        Server();
        Server(std::string ip_address,int port);
        ~Server();
        
        void startListen();
    private:
        int m_socket;
        int port;
        std::string ip_address;
        long message_in;
        unsigned int m_socket_address_len;
        void acceptConnection(int &new_socket);
        std::string buildResponse();
        void sendResponse();
        int m_new_socket;
        std::string server_message;
        int server_start();
        void close_server();
        struct sockaddr_in m_socketAddress;
};

And here is my server.cpp file
#include "server.h"

#include <sstream>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

const int BUFFER_SIZE = 30720;

Server::Server(std::string ip_address,int port)
{
    this->ip_address = ip_address;
    this->port = port;
    this->m_socket_address_len = sizeof(m_socketAddress);
    this->server_message = buildResponse();
    int x = server_start();    
}

Server::Server()
{
}

Server::~Server()
{
}

int Server::server_start()
{
    m_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(m_socket < 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    m_socketAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
    m_socketAddress.sin_port = htons(port);
    m_socketAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip_address.c_str());
    if (bind(m_socket,(sockaddr *)&m_socketAddress, m_socket_address_len) < 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
void Server :: close_server()
{
    close(m_socket);
    exit(0);
}

void Server :: startListen()
{
    if(listen(m_socket,20)<0)
    {
        cout << "Connection Failed" << endl;
    }
    cout  << "\n*** Listening on ADDRESS: " << inet_ntoa(m_socketAddress.sin_addr) << " PORT: " << ntohs(m_socketAddress.sin_port) << " ***\n\n";
    int bytesReceived;

    while (true)
    {
        cout << " Waiting for a new connection " << endl;
        acceptConnection(m_new_socket);

        char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE] = {0};
        bytesReceived = read(m_new_socket, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);
        if (bytesReceived < 0)
        {
            cout << "Failed to read bytes from client socket connection" << endl;
        }
        cout << " Received Request from client " << endl;
        sendResponse();
        close(m_new_socket);
    }
}

std::string Server :: buildResponse()
{
    std::string htmlFile = "<!DOCTYPE html><html lang=\"en\"><body><h1> HOME </h1><p> Hello from your Server :) </p></body></html>";
    std::ostringstream ss;
    ss << "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\nContent-Type: text/html\nContent-Length: " << htmlFile.size() << "\n\n"
           << htmlFile;

    return ss.str();
}

void Server :: acceptConnection (int &new_socket)
{
    new_socket = accept(m_socket, (sockaddr *)&m_socketAddress, &m_socket_address_len);
}

void Server :: sendResponse()
{
    long bytesSent;

    bytesSent = write(m_new_socket, server_message.c_str(), server_message.size());
    if (bytesSent == server_message.size())
    {
        cout << "Server responded to client" << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    //http_server = Server();
    Server server = Server("127.0.0.1",80);
    //  bind(server.m_socket, server.ip_address, sizeof())
    server.startListen();
    return 0; 
}

I have written a server code in c++ and ran it.
It is showing this
*** Listening on ADDRESS: 127.0.0.1 PORT: 80 ***
Waiting for a new connection
But when i ran curl  http://127.0.0.1/ in other terminal
it is showing curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 80: Connection refused
I want to get a connection to my server

Value of x inside the constructor is not checked.

you are not doing any error checking. Just using the return value of bind to then return either 1 or 0 is not sufficient when you ignore that return value. When there is an error errno is set that you should inspect

You have error checking, but you don't actually do anything if you get an error, or say what the error might be.

Also remember that TCP is a byte-streaming protocol, without message boundaries or "packets". There's no guarantee that the data from a single read call will contain a full message. You need to parse the full request to know when and where it ends. And if you close the connection after every request, you need to send back the Connection: close attribute. And technically, you need to send \r\n for each and every newline (IIRC)

As for your problem, you need to debug your server program to see what happens. Either add a lot of logging output, or use a debugger to step through the code.

Your local firewall could be blocking the connection. But really, just use your debugger.

Your code is functional, I have compiled & tested it - but as mentioned by everyone else so far, you need to add better error handling.
For quick and easy hints on where it's failing, use perror() after any socket-related call that returns non-zero (socket/bind/listen/accept etc.)
The bind() call may be failing due to permissions. If that's the case, a simple test is to execute your server as sudo ./server and see if it succeeds.
Style tip: in C++ you don't need to include the keyword struct when declaring a struct sockaddr_in.

Your 80 port is occupied by other application, since you do not check and output the error message when you failed to bind port in the following code.
if (bind(m_socket,(sockaddr *)&m_socketAddress, m_socket_address_len) < 0)
{
  return 1;
}
return 0;

